# mostrar mensaje con imagen en div cuando js esta deshabilitado

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

Tengo un sitio web cuyas funcionalidades utilizan jQuery, envio informacion mediante JSOn y ademas utilizo jQuery Datatables asi que es importante que el usuario tenga habilitado JS en su navegador y ante esto se me ha especificado explicitamente la manera en que debo mostrar el  mensaje al usuario en caso no tenga habilitado javascript: toda la pagina web de inicio en blanco, presentar una imagen centrada y el mensaje al usuario que debe activar javascript.

yo utilizaba primero este div (dentro de etiquetas noscript)para poner toda la pagina inicio en blanco y mostrar el mensaje, lo encontré aca

```
 <div style="position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 3000;
                height: 100%; width: 100%; background-color: #FFFFFF">
                <p style="margin-left: 10px">JavaScript is not enabled.</p>
            </div>
```

y me mostraba toda la pagina en blanco tal como queria y el mensaje en la parte superior izquierda, ahora, no soy bueno en css pero se algo de bootstrap por lo que intente esto para mostrar una imagen centrada y el mensaje bajo la imagen

```
<div style="position: center; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 3000;
            height: 100%; width: 100%; background-color: #FFFFFF">
                <div class="jumbotron">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div style="position: center; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 3000;
            height: 100%; width: 100%; background-color: #FFFFFF">
                            <img src="~/Imagenes/logo%20empresa.png" class="img-responsive" />
                            <p style="margin-left: 10px">
                                Para utilizar las funcionalidades completas de este sitio es necesario tener
                                JavaScript habilitado. Aquí están las <a href="http://www.enable-javascript.com/es/"
                                                                         target="_blank">instrucciones para habilitar JavaScript en tu navegador web</a>.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

y si me muestra la imagen y el mensaje centrada pero el fondo es blanco y me muestra bajo este mensaje la pagina inicio y lo que busco es que solo se muestre el mensaje y toda lo demas de la pagina inicio en blanco.

podrian ayudarme por favor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viendo lo que necesitas sería de está manera:

**HTML:**

```
<noscript>
    <div class="enable">
        <div class="enable-center">
            <span>JavaScript is not enabled.</spanp>
        </div>
    </div>
</noscript>
```

**CSS:**

```
.enable {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: white;
    color: black;
    font-size: 24px;
    z-index: 999;
}

.enable-center {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```